# Why, in general, consanguineous marriage is not allowed?

Tags: marriage, manu-smriti, smriti, sex, parashara-smriti

I have seen in my society that cousin marriage is not encouraged. What is the basis of this view? I am asking about scriptural injunctions. Has Smritis categorically disapproved it?

I have seen these questions, which all discussed the exceptional case of South India, where it is allowed.

[How can Sage Kashyap marry daughters of Daksha, even they are parallel cousins?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7043/how-can-sage-kashyap-marry-daughters-of-daksha-even-they-are-parallel-cousins)

[Cross-cousin marriage and hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21766/cross-cousin-marriage-and-hinduism)

[Cross-cousin(mother's sister's daughter) marriage? [Please refer to questions I linked]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45007/cross-cousinmothers-sisters-daughter-marriage-please-refer-to-questions-i)

I am from the Eastern part of India. It is not allowed here. From the above discussions, I understood that it is not permitted in North India also. So, in general, why it is not allowed?

Comment: Actually, in the *Braja Region* (North India) - it's allowed or even sometimes practised these days amongst the maternal cousins. A guide there told me that they derive this from the *Subhadra-Arjuna* marriage relationship. So the marriage between the progenies of a Sister and Brother is possible.

Comment: @Vivikta - yes there are 2 type of cousin marriage, sagotra, and non-sagotra i.e. mausi's son/daughter wedding mama's daughter/son is acceptable according to Shastras, atleast in Dravida desh (below Vindhyas), but not father's brother's siblings wedding each other - which, btw, is done in Islamic cultures (hence the higher rate of inbreeding).

Comment: These are locally varying customs & traditions @mar , no pan-Indian religious consensus on these. In our area, this kind of "cousin-involving" marriages will be frowned/detested upon, and more importantly, will be impossible to be done via "elders-permission" or the "social -consensus".

Comment: @Vivikta - yes, that's why I said it is accepted in Dravida Desh (below Vindhyas). It doesn't supersede local/family/elder customs, Manu himself says so - follow local customs as long as it doesn't contradict global ones. Since it's an optional, not mandatory to marry non-sagotra cousins. but definitely sagotra cousins are banned, and non-sagotra cousins are not banned.

Comment: As Swami Vivekananda pointed out, different codes hold sway in different parts of India. In Bengal, the code of Raghuandana; farther the code of Mitakshara; other parts the code of Manu. In Nepal, other. These are all local customs, they are neither sanctioned or condemned by the vedas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two verses from Manu Smriti against consanguineous marriage.

[Manu Smriti 11.171](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202065.html)

On having had intercourse with one’s **sister born of his father’s sister**, or **of his mother’s sister**, or **of his mother’s full brother**,—one should perform the Cāndrāyaṇa.

[Manu Smriti 11.172](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202066.html)

**A wise man should never take these three as his wife**; being blood-relations, they are not fit to be married; because by marrying them, one sinks low.